# LINQ to SQL stored procedures issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to learn more about web development with C# and ASP.Net.

I am using LINQ to store values from a contact form in a database, however, the database also requires a 'Policy ID' that is generated by calling a stored procedure.

I have absolutely no idea how to about calling the stored procedure, obtaining the integer value generated and then using that value to set PolicyID in the table.

Could anybody provide me with a process that will work like so:

Execute SPROC, return POLICY ID.
Get PolicyID, set as PolicyNo.
add PolicyNo to db.PolicyID

I appreciate some of this information may appear quite amateurish, but I have never used LINQ nor Stored Procedures before. I have been a front end developer up until now.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here is the C# code used so far:

```
using (MagTestDataContext context = new MagTestDataContext())
    {
        //create new instance of tblPolicy object
        tblPolicy policy = new tblPolicy();
        var policyNo = context.spNextPolicyID();
        //add values to field
        policy.PolicyID = policyNo;
        policy.PolicyHolder = tbName.Text;
        policy.EMail = tbEmail.Text;
        policy.Telephone = tbTelephone.Text;
        policy.Address1 = tbAddressLine1.Text;
        policy.Address2 = tbAddressLine2.Text;
        policy.Address3 = tbAddressLine3.Text;
        policy.Address4 = tbAddressLine4.Text;
        policy.PostCode = tbPostcode.Text;
        policy.ExtraInfo10 = tbInsurer.Text;
        policy.ExtraInfo11 = ddReason.Text;
        policy.ExtraInfo12 = tbOther.Text;
    }
```

Comment: Downvoters: It's courteous to say why you did it.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried? What was the error you are getting?

Comment: I didn't downvote but just a few thoughts: LINQ doesn't support any data persistence. You must be using something else to store the data. Also, if you're looking for the best help here, it's advisable to list what you've tried so far, including any code that may have not worked.

Comment: code added. As i have said, this is my first time using LINQ so a useful comment rather than a downvote would have helped.

Comment: One thing you haven't said it what error you are getting?  In your code you are calling the Stored Proc, which means you have pulled it into the dbml designer so that it appears as a method.  Is this returning a value?  Very difficult to answer as we can't see your dbml design or the stored proc code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using Entity Framework. If so, then you can execute a stored procedure using:

```
using (MagTestDataContext context = new MagTestDataContext())
{
    var policyid = db.ExecuteQuery<int>("DECLARE @ret INT; EXEC spNextPolicyID @ret OUTPUT; SELECT @ret").Single();
}
```

Comment: Well the solution worked to a point, i am not using the Entity framework (that I can see), but used the following code:
    var policyNo = context.ExecuteQuery<int>("spNextPolicyID {0}").First();
I am now getting the following error:
"Incorrect syntax near '0'."

Comment: Yup that was a copy-paste error on my part (I edited my post). You can remove the `{0}` completely from the statement.

Comment: And BTW you're using LINQ-to-SQL to store the data. LINQ is a generic query language you can use on all enumerable object types, not just SQL data.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Have correct, now have the following error - Procedure or function 'spNextPolicyID' expects parameter '@PolicyID', which was not supplied. Guessing I need to put @PolicyID within the brackets?

Comment: Is `@PolicyID` an output parameter?

Comment: In the sproc, @PolicyID is referred to in the following line (which calls another sproc) `exec dbo.spNextIDNumber @PolicID Output, 'PolicyID'`

Comment: See my edit above. It's a hack to get you going, but you should probably do a bit of research on using Stored Procedures here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that all worked fine. I was looking around for a good resource too, so thanks also for the link.